# Merge two input range

Tags: html, css, angular

I want to merge two input range draggable thumbs and STOP dragging when they are overlapping. I also want to change the range track color, but `input::-moz-range-track` is not working.

This is my current code.

```css
.price-slider {
  position: relative;
  width: 420px;
  margin: 0 auto 20px;
  height: .8em;
  text-align: center;
}

.price-slider input {
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 15px;
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  height: .8em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.price-slider input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #1E86D2;
  border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
  width: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

.price-slider input::-moz-range-thumb {
  pointer-events: all;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  outline: 0;
  widows: 24px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  background-color: white;
  border: 2px solid black;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div class="price-slider">
              <input type="range" min="0" #range1 value="0" max="100" step="1"  (input)="range1.value" (mouseup)="stop(range1.value, range2.value)">
              <input type="range" min="0" #range2 value="100" max="100" step="1" (input)="range2.value">
              <label for=""> Range: {{ range2.value - range1.value }} </label>
            </div>
```

Hope someone is gonna help me. Thank you in advance.